# Overflow:hidden includes float in container - why?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I was searching for a solution on how to include floating elements in their container (by default, they fall out of it if it's too short). I found the answer on Stackoverflow to set `overflow` to `hidden` for the container and indeed it worked. But my question is: why? Spec for `overflow: hidden` on w3cschools states:

> This value indicates that the content is clipped and that no scrolling user interface should be provided to view the content outside the clipping region.

So I'd rather expect the part of the float to be clipped than the container to be extended to include the float. Which rule applies here?

---

Example:

```html
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <p>Ala ma kota</p>
        <div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
    </div>
```

And fixed:

```html
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
        <p>Ala ma kota</p>
        <div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello. I found this interesting, would you mind posting a code snippet?

Comment: What do you mean "container to be extended"?  Are you setting height and width attributes for the parent?

Comment: And maybe the element that you might be placing in the container, it is possible that the element maybe having some padding or margin. Due to which it was overflowing earlier. With overflow:hidden, the padded spacing must have been clipped

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal I added snippets with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a reason of setting `overflow` to `hidden`. It works with every value different of `visible`, `initial` or `inherit`.

With any of those values, the overflow renders outside the element's box, as it's said in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

For any other value, the overflow renders inside the div.

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear float. You can read more here https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/.

Code snippet below.

```html
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <p>Ala ma kota</p>
        <div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's not what the question is about.